# Checking if there is only one Database entry in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have the table `item` which each user can add and delete as many as they want, however I want that there is always atleast one entry in `item`.

There is this dirty way but there sure are better ways.

My solution:

```
$items = item::all();

foreach($items as item)
{
    $a++;
}

if ($a > 1) {
    delete_item();
    return back();
} else {
    return back();
}
```

There must be a cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could [use the `count()` method from QueryBuilder/Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#aggregates). It returns the number of items in your table:

```
$totalOfItems = Items::count();

if ($totalOfItems > 1) {
    delete_item();
}

return back();
```

This way, if the total of items in your table is bigger than `1` your `delete_item()` operation will do its job, otherwise, it will just return back.

Hope that this helps you.

Comment: To strictly adhere to OP's request it should be `>= 1` since the current solution will prevent users from deleting the 1st to last entry.

Comment: `however I want that there is always *atleast one entry in item*` is what he wanted, so I think the answer is correct. Even his own code sample, which he says works for him - though it's dirty - uses `> 1`

Comment: His code uses a for loop which starts counting at 0, the count function returns the amount of elements so his implementation does indeed state `>1` but will behave as if the count `>= 1` due to this 0 indexing.

Comment: The code his adds does not show the start value of `$a` but, let's suppose that, yes, it starts at 0. If there's no item inside $items it will go to the else and `return back()`, correct?

If it has 1 item inside $items, it will **also** go to else branch and `return back()`, right? After all 1 is not greater than 1.

If we add `>= 1`, which would be positive for 1 item inside `$items`, it would enter the if branch and delete the item, thus going against **having at least one item inside**.

Comment: If it's 0 or 1, we want it to do nothing (don't delete it), or did he ask the opposite?

Comment: @ErickPatrick There is always atleast 1 item, so it was safe to assume that $a starts as 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to be the default behavior, you can add event listener on `deleting` event and use `count()`.
Check the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#events) for specific details on which laravel version